# What are the physical concepts that can be associated with the operation of a hydraulic arm?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, fluid-statics, home-experiment

I am developing a project that requires an explanation of the physical concepts behind something applicable, like in the industry. I have chosen to describe the concepts behind the operation of a hydraulic arm.I know that the main concepts behind its operation are the following:

- Fluid pressure;
- Work and kinetic energy;
- Pascal's principle;
- Compressibility of fluids.

My doubt is: Is there any other concepts besides these? I think, for example, that angular momentum (behind the rotation of the arms) could be one.

Could you give any insights? I would be grateful with the help.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider

- Force multiplication, i.e. if pressure is the same, larger area means larger force, as P=F/A
- Control feedback to maintain a load, though that may be beyond the scope you are considering